# Laravel: import custom class to migration file

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to import the class as in [this article](http://laraveldaily.com/how-to-use-external-classes-and-php-files-in-laravel-controller/) has been explained (method 3):

**database/migrations/****_createOrdersTable.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

use App\Extenders\References;

class CreateOrdersTable extends Migration {
// ...
}
```

I got the error

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'App\Extenders\References' not found
```

`composer dump-autoload` was not help.

Comment: Why are you using this line `use App\Extenders\References;` ?

Comment: I just need this class. The purpose of this class is not important in this question; it could be any other class.

Comment: Verify that your namespacing is correct in App\Extenders\References and ensure that your composer file has a classmap section for the migrations. I just tried with a class I have within my App folder and was successful.

Comment: @Matt McAlister, I used copy/paste, so there is no typing error in the path... Do you mean `composer.json` or `composer.lock`?

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to declare namespace in `References` class:

```
namespace App\Extenders;
```